# What do you say when you want someone to go with you?

Tags: vocabulary

The question is in the title. So, is it OK to say:

> I don't mind walking home as long as **you accompany me** to go home.

Or is there an alternative expression else? I'm not really familiar with "accompany" by the way. I usually use "would you go with me" to avoid using "accompany" (if that's appropriate in this situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Accompany" is a fine word to use there, but it takes both a direct and an indirect object—you do not need the infinitive "to go:"

> I don't mind walking home as long as you **accompany me home**.

You could insert (or substitute) a prepositional phrase:

> I don't mind walking home as long as you **accompany me along the way [home]**.

Alternatives to "accompany me home" might be

- come along with me
- come with me
- come home with me
- go with me
- go along with me
- join me
- walk me home

Comment: First, I'd like to say thanks for the answer. About the infinitive-to, can I use that in form of accompany+somebody+to+place. E.g. accompany me to the police station. Here's the related link about that use: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22accompany%20me%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2008,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @user, the "to" used in that form is not part of an infinitive; it is a preposition connecting the verb and the object. It is necessary when the object takes an article: "accompany **to the** police station" and "accompany **to the** house" but "accompany home" without "to the."